# PHP nesting for loop inside for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, nested-loops

Been trying to figure this one out for the last 3 hours and so hard to find any search results for "nesting for loop inside for loop", so I must ask this question and somebody can help clarify, as much of an amateur question this is, will much appreciate any and all help.

So I have this block of code underneath, for a beginners looping exercise I found at http://www.w3resource.com/php-exercises/php-for-loop-exercises.php 
on question 3 of that page. The end result should be on that page as well.

```
<?php
    for($a = 1; $a <= 5; $a++) {
        for($b = 1; $b <= $a; $b++) {
            echo "*";
            if($b < $a) {
               echo " ";
            }
        }
        echo "<br />";
    }
?>
```

It turns out like a triangle shape made up of 15 little `*`

I am trying to figure out exactly how this works, as even though the site has an answer, I want to understand so I can write things myself instead of copy pasting.

Below is what I have been able to make out after reading `php.net` and also trying to look for a solution on Google.

So, the `$a` `for` loop starts off as true so loop continues onto the `$b FOR` loop, it is true so it will echo `*`, At this point `$b` is not `< $a` as loop is not yet over so the `++` have not been added yet and `if` statement is false, so we `<br />` and re-run loop.

Second time around. Now `$a=2` and `for` loop is still true so it will go on to `$b` for loop and echo `*`. This is where I get confused. The `$b` has `++` at the end of its statement, so doesn't it mean that after loop 1 `$b = 2` and `if` is still false ?

In my head I keep thinking it should print out like:

`<br />* <br /> * <br />`

instead of this:

`<br />* <br /> * * <br />`

My conclusion.

1. The `$b` value will reset back to 1 after each loop and repeats itself until `if` statement is false.

OR

2. The `*` that get printed are stored and will be the automatic starting point at the beginning of each loop. I understand that if doing a simple print for a `for($i=0;$i<11;$i++)` loop will carry the value over, however in my situation, a printed `*` is not a value, so it shouldn't be carried over to a new loop.

OR

3. I am just completely off with both my conclusions.

Either way, its been confusing me so badly.

Sorry for long explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question now? Like how does this work?

Comment: Replace echo " "; with echo "&nbsp"; bacause html treats multiple spaces as whitespace and evaluates them to a single space

Comment: This question belongs on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hey @Rizier123 , yeah sorry for making it confusing, i am finding it hard to understand how this works. I have written down 2 conclusions for why i think this works but not sure if any of them are correct. I know it's weird that i am asking about a working code block, but it's bugging me so badly that i don't know WHY it works =\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take things one step at a time

**Outer Loop**

```
   for($a = 0; $a <= 5; $a++) {
      //inner loop  here
      echo "<br>";  //after the inner loop has executed, start a new line
    }
```

Start at 0, go up to 5 and do whatever is written inside. Now that means two things will happen for each iteration

1) Inner loop will be executed for every iteration of the outer loop

2) An HTML row break will be printed for every iteration of the outer loop

Now what does the **Inner Loop** do?

```
    for($b = 1; $b <= $a; $b++) {
        echo "*";
            if($b < $a) {
                echo " "; // $b<$a means we still have more stars to print on this line
            }
    }
```

Start at 1, go up to the value of `$a`, this $a will come from the outer loop and will be 1 for the first run, 2 for second up to 5. And while doing this, print a `*`; that means for the first time 1 star will be printed because loop will start at 1 and end at 1. For the second time 2 stars, 3rd time three stars and so on.

Now after printing the star, see if this is the last star that this iteration had to print, if it is not that then print a space so that the next time a star is printed there is a space in between.

That's about it :)  Note that your outer loop starts at 1, it should start at 0 to form the required shape correctly.

Now if you are still confused about the `$b<$a` thing, just get rid of it and run your code again and you will notice nothing much has changed except that there are no spaces between the stars and it will be a little easier to understand

```
    for($b = 1; $b <= $a; $b++) {
        echo "*";
    }
```

And oh, `++` after a variable means increment its value by 1. In a for loop that means on the next run add 1 to the value of the counter. You can also write it as

```
for($a=0; $a<=5; $a=$a+1)      // thats the same as $a++;
```

If you wanted the value to increment by more than 1 you could say

```
for($a=0; $a<=5; $a=$a+2)    // a will be 0 , 2, 4
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/228598)**

Comment: Hi @Hanky 웃 Panky , thanks for your great reply, much appreciate you taking the time to help out! I just have a further question on something I'm still finding it hard to wrap my head around. Lets say for e.g 2nd loop around. Now $a=2 and $b=1. How does PHP know to print two * stars ? to re-run loop, wont $b only need to print one * so that it will $b will =$a. Or does it carry over 1 star from previous loop ?

Comment: Hi Hanky Panky, sorry was a typo on my comment i meant:
Lets say for e.g 2nd loop around. Now $a=1 and $b=2

Comment: Actually, I understand now haha, thank god finally. Thanks for your help man, your awesome !! :)

Comment: $a=1, $b=2 would mean start at 1 and go till 2 that means run it 2 times hence two stars as you understood correctly :)